# Guaranteed higher scores from one should query over another

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a Elasticsearch query with three *should queries* of declining importance. How can I assert that documents returned from each *should query* has higher score than those of less importance?

Maybe this could be solved by using some scoring boundary, so that *should query #1* documents are forced into the score interval 30-20, *query #2* into 20-10 and *query #3* into 10-0.

I know I can work with simple boosting, but I think this does not guarantee that results wouldn't "intrude" on other querys' results.